# How to process a .p file in networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, network-analysis

I have been working with networkx api in python when I struck using it on a .p file.

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question.  For example, what is a .p file?  What format is the file in?  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I am working with networkx in python where I'm provided with the file with .p extension which contains the info. of nodes and edges. And I want to load that file in my python program so that I can create a graph out of it.

Comment: My best guess is that it's a pickle file.  Where did you get the file?  look up how to load a pickle file, or better, check with whoever provided the file for how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

So,  I have gone through that documentation of the networkx api and found that theres's a attribute to load pickled files.

```
>>> G = nx.read_gpickle("test.gpickle") or

>>> G = nx.read_gpickle("example.p")
```

You can find the documentation page here:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle.html#networkx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle